# Incrementation of char

Tags: c#, char

I found some question asking how to let char 'B' to return 'C' and then 'D' etc. The answers were quite complex and mostly just overkill.

Why not to use simply this:

```
char X='A';
X++;
```

EDIT: It goes from A to Z and what next?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're happy with the results that gives, then that's fine.

Usually when I've seen questions like that, they want to wrap from "Z" to "AA" or something like that that though - like Excel columns. Clearly just incrementing a char won't do that - it would go to '['.

Alternatively, even within a single character, the range of valid values may be non-contiguous - the obvious example being hex. If you increment '9' you get ':' instead of the 'a' or 'A' which you probably wanted. The desired order is rarely "whatever Unicode gives you".

Answer (score 45):

If you just want to increment :

```
Char x = 'A';
Char y = (Char)(Convert.ToUInt16(x) + 1);
```

But, if you want an excel like column :

```
    // (1 = A, 2 = B...27 = AA...703 = AAA...)
    public static string GetColNameFromIndex(int columnNumber)
    {
        int dividend = columnNumber;
        string columnName = String.Empty;
        int modulo;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
            dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
        }

        return columnName;
    }

    // (A = 1, B = 2...AA = 27...AAA = 703...)
    public static int GetColNumberFromName(string columnName)
    {
        char[] characters = columnName.ToUpperInvariant().ToCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            sum *= 26;
            sum += (characters[i] - 'A' + 1);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: I dont like ++ on a Char, that's all ^^
And A = 65, Z = 90
a = 97, z = 122
A Char++ like you want did not give you only letters, but symbols like [ ^ ¨ , ; 
So, if you want letters, you have to limit the range.
If you want Excel like columns name, the code I give above.

Comment: Yes I know but I am only using 30 of them so it should work I guess.

Comment: Be carefull :
90 'Z'
91 '['
92 '\\'
93 ']'
94 '^'
95 '_'
96 '`'
97 'a'
If you use 30 till char A (65), you will to til char 95.

Comment: Thanks. I am starting at A and have 30 iterations with ++ so I guess it wont be problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is also intended to go from Z to AA, ala Perl and PHP.