# Add an int to a char in c# to move its ascii value up (just like in c++)

Tags: c#, c++, integer, character

In c++ this code would work:

```
char c='a'; 
int r=2;
c+=r;
```

This would do the same as `c='c'`.
How can I do the same in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incrementation of char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583191/incrementation-of-char)

Comment: maybe you need some kind of cast?

Answer (score 27):

Just cast it to `char` before adding it to `c`

```
char c='a'; 
int r=2;
c += (char) r;
```

Comment: @meyou: Just make sure `c` initial value is not `y` or `z` then it will increment to junk characters.

Comment: hmm I wonder why `char c = 'a' + (char)2;` gives a compilation error?

Comment: You can do `char c = (char)('a' + 2);` instead

Comment: @Andy the reason this happens is because any operation on byte-sized integers has implicit conversion to int - i.e. `'a' + 2` is really `(int)'a' + 2` and so you need to cast it back. IIRC, this is a C++ backwards-compatibility thing but there's quite a bit of discussion on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why