# Increment string value from AAA to AAB to AAC and so on

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given a string `AAB`, how can I return a string `AAC`? I have tried using some of the methods on this answer but am getting an error trying to convert `int` to `char` or vice-versa.

```
public string GetNextPrefix(string prefixToIncrement)
{
    char[] digits = prefixToIncrement.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = previousPrefix.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (digits[i] == 'Z')
        {
            digits[i] = 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;  //error here
            break;
        }
    }
    return new String(digits);
}
```

Update: Duh. Sometimes as soon as I post on here, the answer comes to me just as I post it. The error was:

`Cannot covert source type 'int' to target type 'char'`.

And I solved it by changing that line to:

```
digits[i] = (char) (digits[i] + 1);
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? It'll probably contain a hint as to how to fix it.

Comment: Never written in c# before, but what kind of error will the erroneous line produce? 

Also this will increment all the letters in a string, no? I think you'd need another parameter to tell which character you want to increment.

Comment: I added an edit. It came to me just after i posted the question.

Comment: Don't add the solution to the questiion, post a self-answer. See the [faq].

Comment: @HenkHolterman I would have, but I'll just accept the answer Flat Eric provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast to int and then back to char:

```
digits[i] = (char)((int)digits[i] + 1);
```

Update:

It also works without casting to int:

```
digits[i] = (char)(digits[i] + 1);
```

Comment: You don't need the `(int)` cast.

Comment: This was my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetNextPrefix(string prefix, string format = "000")
{
    const string Charset = "ABCDEF";

    //remove the ToUpper() if you want to expand the charset to contains both cases
    var values = prefix.ToUpper().Select(c => Charset.IndexOf(c));
    if (values.Any(v => v == -1))
        throw new Exception("Invalid Prefix : " + prefix);

    var value = values.Aggregate(0, (acc,v) => acc = acc * Charset.Length + v) + 1;
    var result = String.Empty;

    while(value != 0)
    {
        var remainder = value % Charset.Length;

        result = Charset[remainder] + result;
        value = (value - remainder) / Charset.Length;
    }

    return result.PadLeft(format.Length, Charset[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this results in a type clash:

```
digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;
```

As does this:

```
digits[i] += 1;
```

But this works fine:

```
digits[i]++;
```

Thanks go to: [Incrementation of char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583191/incrementation-of-char)