# Increment a char given a sequence

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Given a sequence of characters, return next following in alphabetical order.

`Example:  given 'A' it should return 'B', 'Z' -> 'AA', 'ZYZ' -> 'ZZA'` etc.

One relevant reference using modulo and math i have found [is in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4583231/1256112). 
Instead of converting it into python, i came up with my own solution.

What would be a more effective algorithmic approach than the one below?

```
import string
def increment_excel(s=''):
    """
    A->B, Z->AA, AZ->BA, KZZ->LAA
    """
    def wrapped(s):
        if not s: 
            return string.uppercase[0]
        ind = string.uppercase.index(s[-1])
        if ind < len(string.uppercase) - 1: 
            return s[:-1] + string.uppercase[ind + 1]
        return wrapped(s[:-1]) + string.uppercase[0]
    return wrapped(s.upper().replace(' ',''))


increment_excel('TRYME') # -> 'TRYMF'
increment_excel('TRY ZZ') # -> 'TRZAA'
increment_excel('ABCC') # -> 'ABCD'
increment_excel('ZZ Z') # -> 'AAAA'
```

Comment: simple generic solution is those were in base-26... convert to base-10, then add 1 to it... again convert to base-26...

Comment: @lokesh1729 there's one little problem in this approach. What letter corresponds to zero?

Comment: yes we have to take care when the number is divisible by zero...then we have to take remainder as 26 and quotient = quotient-1...  say 52.. 52/26=2, so q=1,rem=26 that gives AZ

Comment: Why is `Z` followed by `AA` and `ZZ` also by `AA`?

Comment: `ZZ -> AAA` on my side of interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Please check my solution, I tested from my side and it worked.

```
def seqconverter(a):
    def converter(number):
        retval = str()
        while number:
            x = (number - 1) % 26
            number = (number - 1) / 26
            retval = '%s%s' % (chr(x + 65), retval)
        return retval

    def numconverter(a):
        res = 0
        for c in a:
            res *= 26
            res += ord(c) - 64
        return res
    return converter(numconverter(a) + 1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(seqconverter('ZYZ'))
    print(seqconverter('ZZA'))
    print(seqconverter('XY'))
```

Output:

```
ZZA
ZZB
XZ


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: Too bad your program never returns 'Z'.

Comment: `[convert(i, '') for i in range(50)]
['@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'A', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW']`

Comment: `[convert(i, '') for i in range(1,50)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW']`

Comment: `[convert(i, '') for i in range(670,680)]
[u'YT', u'YU', u'YV', u'YW', u'YX', u'YY', u'Z', u'ZA', u'ZB', u'ZC']`

Comment: @lokesh i see the primary logic but the snippet you provided is not working, besides being far from any PEP standards. Can't upvote in current state

Comment: Yes Agreed... have to put much more effort... can't do it now... but definitely improve my answer.

Comment: `>>> [converter(i) for i in range(670,680)]
['YT', 'YU', 'YV', 'YW', 'YX', 'YY', 'YZ', 'ZA', 'ZB', 'ZC']`

Comment: `>>> [converter(i) for i in range(1,50)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW']`

Comment: @lokesh1729 per requirement `Given a sequence of characters, return next following in alphabetical order`, it's missing a complimentary preparation step of converting "a string to a number to be fed into solution above." In order to accept, your solution must fully satisfy the requirement. Thanks Lokesh.

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but does it beat my own in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @VladNikiporoff I didn't understand your solution, it's a bit complicated for me... what do you mean by efficiency? time, space ?

Comment: Memory consumption and CPU usage. Tried it with 100k, 1m and 10M executions and my solution beat every single time based on execution time.

Comment: Ohh... I see...  @VladNikiporoff

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def increment_excel(s=''):
    arr = list(s.upper().replace(' ', ''))
    if arr:
        arr.reverse()
        n = 1
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if ord(arr[i])+n <= ord('Z'):
                arr[i] = chr(ord(arr[i]) + n)
                n = 0
            else:
                arr[i] = 'A'
                n = 1
        if n == 1:
            arr.append('A')
        arr.reverse()
    return ''.join(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which just uses string manipulation.

Leaving aside the normalization of the string (uppercase it, strip blanks), the function essentially finds the suffix consisting of an optional letter other than <kbd>Z</kbd> followed by any number of <kbd>Z</kbd>s (including none). The trailing <kbd>Z</kbd>s are all changed to <kbd>A</kbd>, while the last character before the <kbd>Z</kbd>s (if any) is incremented. Finally, an <kbd>A</kbd> is prepended if the string consists only of <kbd>Z</kbd>s.

```
import re
import string
succ_tb = string.maketrans(string.uppercase,
                           string.uppercase[1:]+string.uppercase[0])
up_tb = string.maketrans(string.lowercase, string.uppercase)
suff_re = re.compile('(([A-Y]?)Z*)$')

def increment_excel(s):
  return suff_re.sub(
    lambda m: (('' if m.group(2) else 'A') + 
               m.group(1).translate(succ_tb)),
    s.translate(up_tb, ' '))
```